# Running into warnings while starting easyphp 17.0 devserver

Tags: easyphp

I just installed easyphp 17.0 on windows 8.1 64 bit operating system and now facing warning  while starting the http server . 
I have a previous version of easyphp 14.0 installed and think thats what is causing the warning to come up.
I have attached the link to the warning that comes up , It would be grateful if i could find a solution in here.

[List of warnings](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uk6eu0psl8e6c9z/AAC6k84j_vbypUgNUlt9Db_Ra?dl=0)

Thanks
Abi

Answer (score 1):

i was able to successfully run the server as well as database without any warnings once i unistalled the easyphp 14.1 version which i had installed long back.

I think somehow my current easyphp 17.0 was conflicting with my earlier version of easyphp which was 14.1

Thanks 
Abida